# Why do I get an error "modul urllib has no attribute request"?

Tags: python

I try to run my code by doing `python namefile.py` and i get this error
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'`
If i try to import urllib, it says

```
"import" non è riconosciuto come comando interno o esterno,
 un programma eseguibile o un file batch
```

which in English means that he is not recognizing import as a command-

How do I solve this?

Comment: That error comes from `cmd` (the Windows command interpreter), not Python. It means you're trying to type `import urllib` in the Windows prompt, not into Python.

Comment: And how I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the submodule `request` from the parent module `urllib` instead of importing the `urllib` module completely and then trying to access its submodule `request` as an attribute. `import urllib; print(urllib.request)` fails on my machine, too, whereas `from urllib import request; print(request)` and `import urllib.request; print(urllib.request)` works (though I do not know why).